# Chart.js plugin annotation line shadow

Tags: javascript, plugins, chart.js

I work with charts, [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) and use additional plugin [chartjs-plugin-annotation.js](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation).
Here is an example of this code:

https://codepen.io/compwright/pen/mmQMrZ

I want to apply a shadow to the line.
I assume that you can use:

```
ctx.shadowColor = "#000"
ctx.shadowBlur = 3
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 2
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 3
```

Can anyone say how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following plugin:

https://nagix.github.io/chartjs-plugin-style/

Example code for reference:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvasId').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ],
            datasets: [{
                data: ["10", "11", "12", "1", "5"],
                shadowOffsetX: 2,
                shadowOffsetY: 4,
                shadowBlur: 5,
                shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
            }]
        },
    });
```